# Jersey client 2.25 logging not working for request/response traffic

Tags: java, rest, logging, jersey-client

I'm using jersey client v2.25.1 for a REST automation framework and here is how I am registering the Logger and initializing the Client:

```
//Initialize FileHandler
Path currPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
Path logFilePath = Paths.get(currPath.toString(), "logs", testCaseName+".log");
logHandleObj = new FileHandler(logFilePath.toString(), 0, 1, true);

//Initialize Logger
Logger loggerObj = Logger.getLogger(testCaseName);
loggerObj.setUseParentHandlers(false);
loggerObj.addHandler(logHandleObj);

//Initialize ClientConfig
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
//Set configuration features
clientConfig.register(new JacksonFeature());
clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.SUPPRESS_HTTP_COMPLIANCE_VALIDATION, true);
clientInstance = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
//Register LoggingFeature
clientInstance.register(new LoggingFeature(loggerObj, Level.ALL, 
        LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY, LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE));
```

As per [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/logging_chapter.html#d0e15694), this is supposed to be logging complete request/response traffic like so:

```
1 May 09, 2016 2:55:33 PM org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingInterceptor log
2 INFO: 1 * Server has received a request on thread grizzly-http-server-0
3 1 > GET http://localhost:9998/helloworld
....
```

However, I am getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
<log>
<record>
    <date>2017-02-25T15:30:06</date>
    <millis>1488016806253</millis>
    <sequence>0</sequence>
    <logger>org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation</logger>
    <level>WARNING</level>
    <class>org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation</class>
    <method>validateHttpMethodAndEntity</method>
    <thread>1</thread>
    <message>Entity must not be null for http method PUT.</message>
</record>
```

So two problems here:

- Not getting the HTTP traffic
- Format is XML for some reason instead of plain text

Will really appreciate any assistance on this.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking everywhere I went ahead and tried everything I could think of and finally hit a solution.

```
logHandleObj = new FileHandler(logFilePath.toString());
A-> SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();

Logger loggerObj = Logger.getLogger(testCaseName);
A-> logHandleObj.setFormatter(formatter);
B-> loggerObj.setLevel(Level.FINEST);
loggerObj.setUseParentHandlers(false);
```

Adding lines marked with A above fixed the issue with XML format (this was easy) and adding the line marked B fixed the issue with the HTTP traffic not coming up in the log files.

So in conclusion, the `Level` should be explicitly set to `FINEST` for this to work and this is nowhere to be found in the documentation.
Hope this helps someone.